# Not able to get the email for the notifications of ELL

Tags: support

There is a option of getting emails corresponding to the notifications of this site in the link on the topleft corner. I have checkhed the option twice and submitted it but so far I have not been got any emails.

My question is that Does that link/setting work? If yes what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but... Did you click "save" after checking the option?